# Lenovo Thinkpad W520 not booting with Nvidia card enabled

Tags: nvidia, boot-failure, thinkpad, lenovo

On my Lenovo Thinkpad W520 I can switch between Nvidia Optimus or Integrated card. Since a couple of days, My Ubuntu doesn't start any more with the Nvidia card. The boot process stop itself at this point

[image]

And at this moment the fan runs at full speed (because the video card heats a lot, More than in a normal usage) and the disk is not in use.

I don't understand the correlation, But if I start on windows, I plug my monitor in the Display Port and I choose "Disconnect Projector", When I reboot, Ubuntu works (just one time)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have a T520 -- can you choose the "discrete"/optimus option, and not the auto-switching one?

Comment: no, I can choose between nVidia Optimus, Integrated Graphics and Discrete Graphics and if I choose the Discrete one I have this trouble by booting. I also tried o reinstall ubuntu (I did a clean reinstall (I just saved the important config like thunderbird, virtualbox and firefox)) but I still have the same problem...